# iOS - AFNetworking setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock

Tags: ios, azure, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I am using AFNetworking in my iOS application. I need to show progress bar to show the download progress. I was planning to use the method - setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock and use totalBytesExpected, to know the total size of the file. But when I try this against a Azure CDN URL, it returns -1 for totalBytesExpected, totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile. I can see values for other variables - bytesRead, totalBytesRead etc. Can you pls let me know how to present a progress dialog in such a scenario?

```
    [operation1 setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {
                             totalBytesRead = ((totalBytesRead *100)/totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile);
////// Sending Notification about progress
    }];
```

Comment: You can use alamofire its one the best libarary to download files and it has a method to show progress as well https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq, I tried with Alamofire as well. Even this library shows -1 for totalBytesExpectedToRead. I think the problem is with my CDN URL. 'Alamofire.download(.GET, "URL", destination: destination)
      .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
        print("Bytes Read.. \(totalBytesRead) Total Bytes to Read...\(totalBytesExpectedToRead) ")'

Comment: Its an issue with you url does the file exist?? what is the status code when you start the download??

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq, Yes. The file exists. And when I try via the browser as well, the file just downloadsm without showing the total size. May be I need to tweak some property in my Azure CDN